How to support multiple languages in an Angular project using only official libraries
I am fairly new to frontend web programming, and especially new to Angular. I have an Angular project that is written in a certain language (English), I now want to have it available in other languages, but the i18n library creates separate builds (e.g.: dist/en, dist/pt, etc.) for each language. How do I add support for multiple languages while having 1 single build and per my company's rules, only official libraries, no 3rd party ones like "ngx-translate"?
I have tried i18n but it produces separate outputs, I need it all to be hosted on one site.

Strange company rules. Angular i18n is the most performant solution, as the translations are bundled into your app. There is no official solution by Angular for runtime translations. If you cannot use third-party packages, you need to implement it by yourself from scratch.

Runtime translations are not supported by default, you have to use ngx-translate or transloco for example. If you can't use third party libraries, you have to reinvent the wheel, and imo this is a red flag in a company.

Why do you need a single build? Is that also a company policy because if the server is configured correctly then you can serve different versions/translations of the app depending on the Accept-Language HTTP header

Good point @nll_ptr, this is also described in the docs. For the user it would be the same URL, but in the background different content is being served by the web server.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
